# How to fix new view display after segue?

Tags: ios, swift3, segue

I just recently started coding again after about four months. There were a few updates in between. When I went to work on my app I clicked on a link and noticed the new view was hovering over the last view and there was no status bar. Just wanted to know what is causing this to happen and how to fix? Thanks

[image]

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Recover=>SignIn", sender: self)




override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {

if(segue.identifier == "Recover=>Connection") {

let navController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

_ = navController.topViewController as! Connection

}

}
```

Comment: The answer below correct way to present modally, full screen, but you should strongly consider just working with the new modal presentation style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 13 changed the way view controllers are presented by default. If you are using something like
`parentViewController.show(childViewController, sender: self)`
In iOS 12 the child view controller used to be shown full screen. In iOS 13 it shows up hovering over its parent.

To make it show up full screen, you need to add one line above the `show()`:
`childViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`.

Comment: Fixed this but some of my segues are just in storyboard and don't have any code. Is there a solution for this other than having to write code for each segue?

Comment: Change in storyboard presentation style from same ass destination to full screen